# Regex for any name

Tags: regex

I want regex with at least 2 characters start with any alphabet or any  digit not matters.But It can accept - and _ .
Ex : ABD , Abc_123 , 12, A-_ , A1 etc.

Answer (score 0):

(Updated)

`(?=[-\w]{2}).*`

Online test, https://regex101.com/r/JcUaBz/2

Comment: The difference with zipa's answer is no restriction on the third and following letters

Comment: yes...i saw it but I think it will take other special chars too.
as @, #

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
[\w-]{2,}
```

But, if you want to ignore words that have special characters, you can use this:

```
(?<=\s|^)([\w-]{2,})(?=\s+|$)
```